# getting NoReverseMatch.Reverse for '{props.url}' not found.Trying to make a link in django with the name being a dynamic value

Tags: django, reactjs

```
<a href="{% url '{props.url}' %}"><input type='submit' value='REGISTER' id={props.card_id + 
'1'}/></a>
```

Im creating a component where in theres a link which has a name which points to one of the items in urlpatterns of urls.py based of the name value which is in props.url. But im unable to put the value in the href of a tag

Comment: You can't directly call the urls.py file in templates. You can call the particular url from the urlpatterns in the urls.py file using the name assigned to the respective urls

Comment: Yeah i know,how do I put dynamic names in the templates knowing that it's stored in props (props.url actually stores the name not url)my bad for calling it url

Comment: It should be in the form `<a href="{% url '<app_name>.<url_name>' %}"></a>